# How to match the first POSIX `[:cntrl:]` character with older BSD `awk`?

Tags: awk, bsd

I wanted to match the first ASCII control character of an input string with `awk` but I stumbled upon what seems to be a bug on older BSDs:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

printf 'a \b c\n' |

awk 'match( $0, /[[:cntrl:]]/ ) { print RSTART }'
```

```
1
```

The expected output would be:

```
3
```

What could be wrong with the code?

Comment: I get `3` on my OSX (BSD) awk

Comment: @anubhava That would be the expected output

Comment: What is version of your `awk` (output of `awk --version`)?

Comment: @Daweo `awk version 20070501` on macOS Catalina and `awk version 20110810 (FreeBSD)`

Answer (score 3):

What about using a character class designating control characters in this way with hex numbers:

```
$ printf $'a \b c\n' | awk 'match( $0, /[\x01-\x1f]/ ) { print RSTART }'
3
```

Comment: That isn't exactly equivalent to `[:cntrl:]`, `\x00` and `\x7f` are missing; I'm not expecting those to appear but it would be great to have them in the regex. +1

Comment: @Fravadona You can append the `\x7f`; I did not include NUL because it cannot appear in POSIX text files. POSIX lines must not contain NULs. Apparently, as you found out, your awk (which old BSD is it exactly?) has trouble when it appears in a character class in certain positions.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it as I don't have the old version of BSD awk you mentioned but would negating the `[:print:]` character class work there:

```
$ printf $'a \b c\n' | awk 'match( $0, /[^[:print:]]/ ) { print RSTART }'
3
```

I couldn't find a POSIX definition of `[:print:]` but according to [the gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#table_002dchar_002dclasses):

> [:print:] Printable characters (characters that are not control
> characters)

so in theory negating it might work.

Comment: It works for ASCII; but also matches non-ASCII chars, for ex. ``

Comment: ++ve. Just want to check if definition of `[:print:]` is same in all versions of `awk` OR it depends on O.S sir? Just thought to ask this question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 idk but I'd guess it varies based on your locale like all the other character classes do.

Comment: `https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01` ::: `"print
Define chars to be classified as printable chars, including the <space>. In the POSIX locale, all chars in class graph shall be included; no chars in class cntrl shall be included. In a locale definition file, chars specified 4 the keywords upper, lower, alpha, digit, xdigit, punct, graph, & the <space> are automatically included in this class. No character specified for the keyword cntrl shall be specified."` - that's the closest i could find for posix 2018 definition of what `print` entails

Answer (score 1):

1. it's `nawk` that happens to show up in some `BSD-` descendant distributions, but it has nothing to do with `bsd` itself
2. from my personal trial and error attempts, it seems `nawk` can `gsub()` a null byte properly into a replacement string, but there's no way to get `nawk` to print out a null byte, whether it's

-- coming in from `/dev/stdin` or files,

-- requested via `sprintf("%c", 0)`,

-- or hard-coded into a variable, e.g. `myvar = "\0" ;`

`nawk` returns a `1 (true)` for this test when all else returns false :

> ```
>   nawk 'BEGIN { print ("\1"~"\0") }'
>
>   1
> ```

`nawk` in its current form is also very screwy when it comes to invalid data inputs - a simple regex test for existence of a byte results in fatal error :

```
% nawk 'BEGIN { print length(_="\123\321\456\777") }' 
4

% nawk 'BEGIN { print length(_="\123\321\456\777"), (_~"\321") }'

nawk: multibyte conversion failure at ?...
 source line number 1
 context is
    BEGIN { print length(_="\123\321\456\777"), >>>  (_~"\321") <<<
```

… a test that `gawk` in `UTF-8` properly handles without any error messages:

> ```
> LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' LANG='en_US.UTF-8' gawk -e '
>
>     BEGIN { _="\123\321\456\777"; print (_~"\321") }' 
>
> 1
> ```

Comment: You **can** print a `NUL` byte with `nawk`, with `nawk 'BEGIN{printf "%c%c%c\n",0,0,0}' | tr '\0' '.'` . What you **cannot** do is to store `NUL` bytes in a variable, because it means the _end-of-string_ in `nawk`; example with `nawk 'BEGIN{ _ = "-"; sub(/\0/,".",_); print _ }'` and `nawk 'BEGIN{ _ = sprintf("-%c%c%c",0,0,0); gsub(/\0/,".",_); print _ }'`

Comment: @Fravadona : yes you're correct. my oversight. but the funny thing is that in `nawk`, :::::::::::::::::::::: `( "\1" ~ "\0" )` is true, something that should obviously be false